# Using .load() or PHP include to load a file with dependencies

Tags: php, jquery, include, directory

Let's say you downloaded a third party app such as a database browser. You upload it into its own folder in your public_html folder. Instead of sending a user to its internal link, such as www.website.com/App/Login.php, you want to have Login.php loaded on one of your own pages higher up: website.com/Login.php.

The file would contain either:

```
$('#div').load('App/Login.php');
```

or

```
<?php include '/App/Login.php';
```

Unfortunately the PHP method is not working for me at all, and the jQuery method works, however none of the file's dependencies are in-tact. Eg. if App/Login.php was calling for App/js/File.js, it would look in the wrong directory.

Comment: you are missing opening parenthesis on the php, `include("/APP/Login.php");`

Comment: yea sorry just a typo.

Comment: @Magna: _*sigh*_ … `include` is not a function, it is a “language construct”, and __does not need__ parentheses.

Comment: @CBroe, he had it lik `'/App/Login.php');` at first, that's why I suggested he is missing **opening** parenthesis.

Comment: Well for some reason using PHP doesnt work but I got jquery to work.